# Can only have one anonymous define call per script file

Tags: javascript, amd, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm creating monaco editor using loader.js but getting the error "Can only have one anonymous define call per script file" 2 times in console.

```
<script src="/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
```

Code to create editor

```
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '/monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
 require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {                
    monacoEditor= monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('coding-editor'), {
        value: [
        'function x() {',
        '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
        '}'
    ].join('\n'),
    language: 'javascript'
    });
 });
```

I tried to search the issue and found below related answer:

Some piece of code that you are loading is invoking define with an anonymous module id. You could:

**load that code through the AMD loader (i.e. manually require it) such that the AMD loader creates the `<script>` tag.**

**load that code before the AMD loader (i.e. define will not be available to that piece of code)**

**unset define for the duration of evaluation of that script (i.e. if you load it with a `<script>` tag, then unset define before and restore it afterwards)**

**try to unset define.jquery, AFAIK jquery might be checking for that on the define function**

This page has lot of jquery already and I understand this because of jQuery. Please help some to make me understood by example. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue this morning and I applied the second solution.

> load that code before the AMD loader (i.e. define will not be available to that piece of code)

This works because `define` is being called from inside jQuery anonymously, as the error says. Explained further in the [require.js website](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch), which happens to use loader function (define, require) similar to loader.js.

In my case I simply made sure to include my loader after jQuery so the `define`s don't collide.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you did that please?

Comment: @gciochina It's been a while since this, but after reading the context. The change is basically to load any other code using `define` before the loader is included so it doesn't interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to create script by tags, but got aler:'Can only have one anonymous define'
So I just overwrite it :

```
        this.temp_define = window['define'];
        head.appendChild(loaders);
        window['define'] = undefined;
```